# DeprecationWarning: Gatsby-Source-Airtable with mapping to a fileNode

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, deprecated, airtable

I'm getting a Deprecation Warning on Gatsby Build after image mapping: { image: `fileNode` } has been added to the plugin option:

(node:15664) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

```
 {
          resolve: `gatsby-source-airtable`,
          options: {
            apiKey: process.env.AIRTABLE_API_KEY, // specify via env
            tables: [
              {
                baseId: process.env.AIRTABLE_BASE, // specify via env
                tableName: process.env.AIRTABLE_TABLE_NAME, // specify via env
                mapping: { image: `fileNode` },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
```

I've also noticed that gatsby-source-airtable is using gatsby-source-filesystem here and there is no deprecation warning on older gatsby-source-filesystem versions (under 3.0.0)

Not sure if the issue comes from the Airtable plugin or from the Filesystem, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the stacktrace in:

- https://github.com/jbolda/gatsby-source-airtable/issues/285
- https://github.com/jbolda/gatsby-source-airtable/issues/274

> Not sure if the issue comes from the Airtable plugin or from the
> Filesystem, any thoughts?

Definitely, it comes from Airtable side.

None of the links above fixes the issue but they won't break the compilation. For some users, running a completely fresh install made the warning disappear.

Personally, I would suggest running `--trace-deprecation` flag.